# How to get FileName using C# Xamarin OnActivityResult

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, ftp, xamarin.android

Hello Guys I am bit new to Xamarin and I am using Visual Studio 2015 to develop the android application. I am trying to upload the file from mobile to FTP Location. I wrote the Web Service which accepts the byte array and stores the file into FTP Location.

code is something like

```
FtpWebRequest requestFTPUploader = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FTPServer + FileName);
requestFTPUploader.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FTPUserId, FTPPwd);
requestFTPUploader.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
int bufferLength = 2048;
byte[] buffer = documents;
requestFTPUploader.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
using (Stream s = requestFTPUploader.GetRequestStream())
{
    s.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
FtpWebResponse ftpresp = (FtpWebResponse)requestFTPUploader.GetResponse();
string  status= ftpresp.StatusDescription;
```

This works fine however I have to send the filename with extension

for that in android I am using intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetType("image/*");
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select a Photo"), 0);
```

and its OnActivityResult method as below

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data){          
byte[] binData;
Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
Android.Media.Ringtone r = Android.Media.RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(this, uri);
string FileName = r.GetTitle(this);}
```

where i am getting directory of the file not the actual file name.

I even tried various ways. in xamarin studio there is something like data.getData() which returns the Uri which has Filename in it but not sure what is the method i can use equivalent of the same in c# visual studio for Xamarin.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
AJ